# Laravel 5.6 Delete by ID passed as function parameter

Tags: php

I am currently having an issue following a tutorial, when I call a controller method to delete a record by passing an `$id` via URI and trying to execute:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    //dd($id);
    $sql = 'DELETE * FROM albums WHERE id=:id';
    DB::delete($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM albums WHERE id=?' at line 1 (SQL: DELETE * FROM albums WHERE id=:id)

The URI passed is `/album/2/delete` where 2 is the id I parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to include `*` in your DELETE query as you can't delete a column. It's already assuming you're deleting the entire row:

```
DELETE FROM albums WHERE id=:id
```

See the DELETE syntax in the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem, I'm just learning the difference between raw queries and then using the helper, so following step by step.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove * from query.Also in laravel use this code to delete.

DB::table('albums')
->where(['id' => $id])
->delete();
```

Don't write direct queries while you are using a framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is completed code:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    //dd($id);
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM albums WHERE id=:id';
    DB::delete($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```